# Efficient way to make two pairs in python

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I would like to make two pairs from pairs.
A pair consists of two elements, and a two-pair consists of two pairs.
Here is the list of constraints:

1. In a pair, order of elements is important: (element1, element2) != (element2, element1)
2. In a two-pair, order of pairs is not important: (pair1, pair2) == (pair2, pair1)

I wrote pseudo code that satisfies the above constraints as follows:

```
class Pair:
    def __init__(self, element1, element2):
        assert isinstance(element1, Element)
        assert isinstance(element2, Element)
        self.element1 = element1
        self.element2 = element2

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Pair):
            return False
        if self.element1 != other.element1:
            return False
        if self.element2 != other.element2:
            return False
        return True

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not (self.__eq__(other))

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.element1) ^ hash(self.element2)

    def getFirst(self):
        return self.element1

    def getSecond(self):
        return self.element2
```

```
class TwoPair:
    def __init__(self, pair1, pair2):
        assert isinstance(pair1, Pair)
        assert isinstance(pair2, Pair)
        self.pair1 = pair1
        self.pair2 = pair2

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, TwoPair):
            return False
        if self.pair1 == other.pair1 and self.pair2 == other.pair2:
            return True
        if self.pair1 == other.pair2 and self.pair2 == other.pair1:
            return True
        return False

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not (self.__eq__(other))

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.pair1) ^ hash(self.pair2)

    def getFirst(self):
        return self.pair1

    def getSecond(self):
        return self.pair2
```

```
def makeTwoPairs(allPairs):
    allTwoPairs = set([])
    for pair1 in allPairs:
        for pair2 in allPairs:
            if pair1 == pair2:
                continue
            twoPair = TwoPair(pair1, pair2)
            if twoPair in allTwoPairs:
                continue
            else:
                allTwoPairs.add(twoPair)
    return allTwoPairs
```

The function `makeTwoPairs` takes a long time in my code. Is there any other representation for two pairs? Or, can the above code be improved?

Comment: This code does not make any sense to me. What is the actual usecase you are trying to solve? In general deriving from 'tuple' is likely a better approach instead of reinventing wheels here. This code smell like coding-without-actually-knowing-my-problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would probably be better off sticking to standard python datastructures. `tuple` for `Pair` and `set` for `TwoPair` (although you might write a `set` subclass to add the `__hash__` method).

For example:

```
import operator

class TwoPairs(set):
  def __hash__(self):
    return reduce(operator.xor, map(hash, self))
```

Regarding the fact that your `makeTwoPairs` function takes a long time to execute, you can rewrite it like this :

```
def make_two_pairs(all_pairs):
  all_two_pairs = set()
  # uniqify the pairs list
  all_pairs = list(set(all_pairs))
  for i in range(len(all_pairs)-1):
    for j in range(i+1, len(all_pairs)):
      all_two_pairs.add(TwoPairs(all_pairs[i], all_pairs[j]))

  return all_two_pairs
```

You will then produce only *unique* `TwoPairs`, without the combinatorial explosion or the overhead of testing everytime before adding a new pair to your result set.

Comment: Or `frozenset` for `TwoPair`, it's already hashable. Depends whether `element1` and `element2` are supposed to be mutable attributes of `Pair` (and if not, whether `pair1` and `pair2` are for `TwoPair`) - I would presume not, and therefore you're right to propose `tuple`.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you need to write your own classes? I don't see anything in your specification that couldn't be satisfied by using tuples as pairs and sets as two-pairs.

But if you're determined to optimize your own code, always start by profiling. Google "Python profile" and read the first five links or so if you're unsure how.